# salloc: error: Job submit/allocate failed: Invalid feature specification

Tags: slurm

I'm encountering a slurm error.

I logged into slurm controller to verify if slurm is working properly

```
$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug*       up   infinite      8   idle ip-192-168-73-[129,179],.....
```

Checked if nodes are properly recognized

```
$ scontrol show nodes
```

Unsure what is mean't by invalid feature specification

Corresponding salloc command is

```
N2=$(($N*2))
salloc -N $N2 '--constraint=[worker*"$N"&server*"$N"] test' \
           $CLUSTER_SHARED_FOLDER/scripts/$CLUSTER_CONTROLLER_SH \
           2>&1 | tee $CLUSTER_OUTPUT_LOG \
```

Comment: Could you add the full command that is giving you the error?

Comment: addressed that in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was because the the cluster consisted of 8 nodes. However, srun command was

```
N2=$(($N*2))
salloc -N $N2 '--constraint=[worker*"$N"&server*"$N"] test' \
           $CLUSTER_SHARED_FOLDER/scripts/$CLUSTER_CONTROLLER_SH \
           2>&1 | tee $CLUSTER_OUTPUT_LOG \
```

i.e. Number of workers & servers was more than the number of nodes. This mismatch caused the salloc command to give invalid specification error.

The fix was to ensure number of workers = number of nodes available

```
N2=$(($N))
salloc -N $N2 '--constraint=[worker*"$N"] test' \
           $CLUSTER_SHARED_FOLDER/scripts/$CLUSTER_CONTROLLER_SH \
           2>&1 | tee $CLUSTER_OUTPUT_LOG \
```